# Mockito cannot mock java.lang.reflect.Method

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

please help.

I have a class to test against with junit test.
Class

```
@Override
public Object invoke(Object o, Method method, Object[] objects) throws Throwable {
    ...
    final Object toReturn = method.invoke(this.impl, objects);
    ...
}
```

Test class I have

```
@Test
public void test() throws Throwable {
        try {
            APIController apiController = new APIController(paramMock1, new Gson());
            Method method = apiController.getClass().getMethod("ping");
            methodMock = Mockito.mock(method.getClass()); **---> Fail**
            Mockito.doNothing().when(methodMock).invoke(Mockito.anyObject(), Mockito.any());
            proxy.invoke(new Object(), method, new Object[]{});
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Assert.assertTrue(ex instanceof NullPointerException);
        }
    }
```

The error message is

```
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.reflect.Method
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types`
```

I did some research and added

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

on top of test class, but error still comes.

How can I test with a mocked of this Method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PowerMock and Mockito are different mocking frameworks, so just adding the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation would not solve your problem. Powermock *could* be useful (I'm not very familiar with it, so not sure here), but you would need to rewrite the test to use it instead of mockito.

But from what I see you most likely don't need to mock the `Method` class — for your task it would be sufficient to just mock the *object* on which you want to mock the method. Something like this:

```
APIController apiController = mock(APIController.class);
doNothing().when(apiController).ping(...);
// pass the mocked apiController to your proxy;
// test that proxy.invoke calls the ping method
```